# In a distributive lattice, which are the equivalence classes of the projectivity relation on prime intervals?

Tags: lattice-orders, integer-lattices

Let $L$ be a lattice (we can assume that it is distributive), according to [Birkhoff (page 72)](https://math.chapman.edu/%7Ejipsen/summerschool/Birkhoff%201948%20Lattice%20Theory%20Revised%20Edition.pdf):

Two intervals of a lattice are called *trasposes* when they can be written as $[a \wedge b, a]$ and $[b, a \vee b]$ for suitable $a$ and $b$.

Likewise, two intervals $[x, y]$ and $[x', y']$ are called *projective* (in symbols $[x, y] \sim [x', y']$) if and only if there exists a finite sequence $[x, y]$, $[x_1, y_1]$, $[x_2, y_2]$, $\ldots$, $[x', y']$ in which any two succesive quotients are trasposes.

An interval $[a, b] = \{x \in L: a \leq x \leq b \}$ is called *prime* when $b$ covers $a$.

It could be seen that the binary relation of *projectivity* over the set of prime intervals is an equivalence relation.

My question is about two examples of distributive lattices.

In the first example, I want to see which are the equivalence classes of the lattice whose Hasse diagram is presented in this picture (where the nodes are labeled with letters; and edges are labeled with $e_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 42$):

[image]

It should be said that the projectivity relation it is not on the nodes of the Hasse diagram, but on the prime intervals of the Hasse diagram. So, it has not sense to write: ∼; it should be written expresions of the type [,]∼[d,e], because the projectivity relation ∼ is defined over prime intervals. The transitivity property should be understood on intervals, for example: if [,]∼[d,e] and [d,e]∼[g,h], then [,]∼[g,h].

Are [b, d] and [e, h] projective?

I think that they are not projective. Could someone confirm that?

If this is true, and we choose a color for each equivalence class of projective intervals: Is the following diagram correct?

[image]

The second example is the following:

**Edit:** I've changed the images of the second example

[image]

The questions are the same as in the first example. Is the following diagram correct?

[image]

**Edit:** I've heard somewhere that the number of equivalence classes of the projectivity relation, in a distributive lattice, equals the length of one maximal chain. Could someone give me a reference of this stament?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are right about the first. The second example is not a lattice, let alone a distributive one. By the way, it would be so much friendly to other users if you post those images rather than links... At least that's what I think

Comment: There doesn't exist $d \wedge x$ at least for $x \in \{a,b,e\}$

Comment: I see now your point about the relation being on the intervals, my bad. I'm now in the middle of something else, so I can't proceed to a chat.

Comment: Thanks amrsa! regarding the first comment, you have reason: $d \wedge x$ doesn't exisit, now I understand your comments. If you allow me, I will change de diagram of the second example.

Comment: Ok, I'll come back latter. Meanwhile I'm deleting some of non-sensical comments I made, to clean this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this sort of problem is to apply Birkhoff's
Representation Theorem for distributive lattices.  To apply it as an
algorithm:  (1) Call $B$ the set of all of the join-irreducible elements of the
lattice, that is, all elements that cover exectly one element.  In
your first lattice, listing them in rank order from the bottom, the
join-irreducibles are:  $b$, $c$ and $d$, $g$, $f$ and $k$, $r$, $j$ and $x$, $q$, $w$, and
$D$.  (2) $B$ inherits a $\le$ relationship from the lattice, and is
thus a partially-ordered set.  (3) Consider $J(B)$, the lattice of (lower)
order ideals of $B$ under the usual set operations of subset, union,
and intersection.  Birkhoff's Representation Theorem is that $J(B)$ is
isomorphic to the original lattice.  Each
element of the lattice corresponds to the order ideal of $B$ which is
the set of join-irreducibles that are $\le$ the element of the
lattice.  (4) Whenever $a$ covers $b$ in the lattice, the order ideal
corresponding to
$a$ contains exactly one more element of $B$ than the order ideal
corresponding to $b$.

In a modular lattice, projectivity of prime intervals is the
transitive closure of the transposes that are shown by "cover
diamonds", sets $a, b, a \wedge b, a \vee b$ in which all four
relations are cover relations.  And you can see that upper-left and
lower-right sides of
any cover diamond correspond to adding the same element of $B$ to the lower
element of the edge to create the upper element of the edge; and
similarly for the upper-right and lower-left sides.  The result is that
if two covers are projective, they involve the same element of $B$.
Conversely, if two covers $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ add the same element of $B$, they are both transposes of $[a \vee c, b \vee d]$ and thus
projective.  (Distributivity guarantees the latter interval also adds the same element of $B$.)
Thus projective equivalence classes of covers correspond to the
elements of $B$.

Using this, you can read off the Hasse diagram that the equivalence
classes you've shown are correct.  E.g. $\{e_5, e_7, e_9\}$ corresponds
to adding $g$ to the order ideal.

One consequence is Thrall's theorem:  Every maximal chain in the
lattice corresponds to a sequence of order ideals of $B$, starting
with the null set, adding one element at a time, and finishing with the
whole lattice.  Thus the length of a maximal chain equals the size of
$B$, which equals the number of projective equivalence classes of covers.
Similarly, the number of maximal chains in the lattice equals the
number of linearizations of the partial order of $B$.

Comment: Thanks Dale! great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question about if [b, d] and [e, h] are projective, you are right, they are not projective.

Therefore, The picture of the fisrt example with colors, is correct.

The same can be said for the second example, the picture of the second example with colors is correct.

The theoretical justification, can be seen in the book that you have mentioned (Birkhoff, Lattice Theory) on page 76, exercise 1, where is stated that opposite sides of a quadrilater represent transposed prime intervals in a finite modular lattice. As your two examples are even distributive, the statement is true.

Regarding the reference you are requesting at the end, in the article "On the projective structure of a modular lattice" of Thrall, in the introduction is stated that in a distributive lattice, the number of equivalence classes under the relation of projectivity
equals the length of any maximal chain.

Hope it will be useful!